# MongoDB query on all sharded collections without shardkey

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-query

I have several shard-(ed) collections.
The collection is user requests. and the shard key is User Id.

I have a field named "Execution Time" 
and I want query all the requests in a period of time (lte and gte).

The index is with the shard key, but my query is without.
I would like not to put all the shard Key in query with a "in" operator because I have a 1000 shard keys (users)..
futher more to do that i need to get all user ids on every query - it means 2 queries each time instead of 1.

But still i want to use an index.. 
what option is to add userId > 0 < maxUserId to the query?

What is the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there enough information?

Answer (score 1):

For ideal performance, shard keys should be chosen in a way the router (`mongos`) can tell which shard will have the data for the most common queries. This is only possible when the find-query has a criteria which is also the shard-key.

But in this case it is impossible for the router to tell which shard has the data for the query. It is not unlikely that there are relevant results on every shard. In that case the query needs to be forwarded to all shards, which will process it simultaneously. But when you have an appropriate index, this will help them doing so.

Comment: i need data from all the collections. so what is the appropriate index?

Comment: @stackoverflowNewB That question doesn't make sense. An index always applies to only one collection. Also, a find-query always returns data from only one collection. When you need data from more than one collection, you need to create a separate index for every collection and need to query each collection separately.

Comment: mongodb documents says that i must put shard key in the index. i don't understand why must, and what will happen if i dont

Comment: ok Philipp - so you say i must to add the shard keys into my query.. thanks for your reply i'll edit my question so it will be more clear